# Bootstrap: How to collapse heading panel (link on minus)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap collapsing panels which are by default collapsed.

When I click on + icon or somwhere on header title I **can open** that panel and see content in it, but when panel is opened **the minus sign** for collapsing panel is not linkable (header title is).

So, I want to make that minus icon is linkable (under HTML code is css part and you can find minus icon on content: "\f273"; in class .panel-collapse .panel-heading:after )

**Update**

There is online example:
link is http://byrushan.com/projects/ma/1-6-1/jquery/light/components.html
and go down to the **Collapse->Accordion**

(When you are expanding panel its find, but on collapsing - (minus) is not linkable)

There is my code

```
<div class="panel-group" data-collapse-color="red" id="faq" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

          <div class="panel panel-collapse">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#faq1" aria-expanded="false">
                          Panel 1
                      </a>
                  </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="faq1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Text in panel
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          ... (more DIV-s with panels)
      </div>
```

Here is related CSS files

```
.panel-collapse .panel-heading {
  position: relative;
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading .panel-title > a {
  padding: 8px 5px 16px 30px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading .panel-title > a:after,
.panel-collapse .panel-heading .panel-title > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all;
  -o-transition: all;
  transition: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading .panel-title > a:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading:not(.active) .panel-title > a:before {
  background: #eee;
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading:before,
.panel-collapse .panel-heading:after {
  font-family: 'Material-Design-Iconic-Font';
  font-size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all;
  -o-transition: all;
  transition: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 4px;
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading:before {
  content: "\f278";
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  content: "\f273";
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading.active .panel-title > a:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading.active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: scale(0) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: scale(0) rotate(-90deg);
}
.panel-collapse .panel-heading.active:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-top: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

because there is no answer, i will add my workaround

```
.panel-collapse > .panel-heading > .panel-title > a {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

basically it will make `<a>` tag over the minus sign and `<a>` will be clickable